# VirtualBox Ubuntu VM (Windows host) stops resolving names after connecting to VPN on host

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, virtualization, virtualbox

I am running a Lubuntu guest VM on my Windows 10 host using VirtualBox (`6.0.10r132072`). Everything works fine network wise.

When I connect to my company VPN, in most cases the VM loses ability to resolve names.

- In Firefox it doesn't open any sites (e.g. github.com: `Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at github.com.`).
- Though I am able to connect to our company Jenkins using IP address in the URL (e.g `http://11.0.11.111:8080/job/deployment/job/master/30/console`)
- I'm also able to ping `8.8.8.8` and get response

If I reboot my VM, everything starts working fine. I compared output of `ifconfig` before and after reboot it's the same (except things like `RX packets`)

Question: **Is there anything I can do to avoid this restart? Can I just restart some service on the VM instead?**

---

My public IP (googled what is my IP): `207.108.xxx.yyy`

Windows host `ipconfig`

```
  C:\Users\12345465>ipconfig

  Windows IP Configuration


  Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : company.corp.local
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 1234::d50:de8e:52f6:4de8%9
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 1234::64f0:2f92:4da6:55c9%9
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.102.28
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
                                         172.16.123.4
  Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 1234::3c3e:6640:4e25:d1e6%23
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.1
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 3:

     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
     Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : 1234::1d8a:307:5056:86e6%2
     IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.105
     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.123.1

  C:\Users\12345465>
```

Lubuntu guest `ifconfig`:

```
  17:00:26-kash$ ifconfig

  enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet 111.22.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 111.22.2.255
          inet6 fe80::7c:910:4429:b3a2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
          ether 08:00:27:06:de:d8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 76337  bytes 70214530 (70.2 MB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 41976  bytes 5820689 (5.8 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
          inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
          inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
          loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
          RX packets 39966  bytes 20275695 (20.2 MB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 39966  bytes 20275695 (20.2 MB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

  17:09:51-kash$
```

Lubuntu release:

```
    16:50:49-kash$ cat /etc/*rele*
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
    VERSION_ID="18.04"
    HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
    SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
    PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
    VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
    UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
    16:51:01-kash$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the VPN is pointing your local resolver to your company DNS servers.

Start with checking where your VM gets it's DNS from before you open the VPN:

On the Windows host, try this command:

```
nslookup example.com
```

This should give you something like the following

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup example.com
Server:  gw.local.domain.com
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    example.com
Addresses:  2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
          93.184.216.34
```

The line `Server:  gw.local.domain.com` shows you what DNS server answered the query, which is your default DNS resolver. Do this after enabling the VPN, and you'll probably see a change.

You can do the same thing on the Ubuntu VM this command

```
dig example.com
```

Your output should look something like this

```
user@localhost:~$ dig example.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46803
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.   IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.  2424 IN A 93.184.216.119

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan  9 16:07:09 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

The line `;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)` shows you which server answered the query.

Now, if you want to see the settings change, or modify the DNS resolver settings, you can do it here.

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, you'll need to check it in some different places.

Some documentation here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/. You'll want to add nameserver config for the specific interface you are using.

If it's 18.04 or newer, check this file:

```
/etc/netplan
```

If it's older than 18.04 check this file

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Now, presumably, VirtualBox is using the host to resolve DNS queries, or it just adds the same settings as the host NIC is using.

On the Windows host, run the following command to show you the configured DNS servers

```
ipconfig /all
```

This might give you some hints to what servers are configured on the two systems.

Comment: On the VM I see `;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)`, which is quite different from what I see on Windows `Server:  md6prddc02.company.corp.local
Address:  xx.0.0.5y`, this is when everything is working fine.

Comment: I added   `ethernets:\n    enp0s3:\n      nameservers:\n          addresses: [ xx.0.0.5y, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]` to my `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` and did `sudo netplan apply`, works now. Where `xx.0.0.5y` came from `nslookup google.com` on host. Thank you!

Comment: 127.0.0.53 seems to be a local DNS resolver, probably something that VirtualBox adds to get DNS working on the VM.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar Problems. The accepted Answer in this link resolves my Problems: https://superuser.com/questions/641933/how-to-get-virtualbox-vms-to-use-hosts-dns

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "<VM name>" --natdnshostresolver1 on
```

See also http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy